# How to run PowerShell Invoke-Command from Command Prompt when the script has a switch?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I have the need to run PowerShell scripts using the command prompt (calling `powershell.exe` with the `-c` parameter).  I have run these for years but have never tried it with `Invoke-Command` in order to do remoting and when the script I want to execute has a switch I have to pass.

This piece of code works great from PowerShell, a simple script that has the LogRun switch:

```
icm -cn MYCOMPUTER02 {C:\Temp\Write-to-File.ps1 -LogRun $Using:LogRun}
```

However, when I run it via the Command Prompt with `powershell.exe` fails:

```
powershell -c "icm -cn MYCOMPUTER02 {C:\Temp\Write-to-File.ps1 -LogRun $Using:LogRun}"
```

I have tried many variations of this and nothing works, I am sure I missing some syntax detail or some quotes somewhere.

Please let me know if you can help me figure this out.

This is the error I get:

```
icm : The value of the using variable '$using:LogRun' cannot be retrieved
because it has not been set in the local session.
At line:1 char:1
+ icm -cn MYCOMPUTER02{D:\PatV2DU\PatV2DUService20180411120032\Sc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Command], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UsingVariableIsUndefined,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: Running inside PS, `$Using:LogRun` has meaning. From the command line, it does not.

Comment: So how do you do it then?

Comment: What is `$LogRun` in the first place?

Comment: $LogRun is a switch. For example, you have this script: param([switch]$LogRun) if ($LogRun) {DoWork}

Comment: I showed how it works when you use invoke-command directly from PowerShell, but when I try to run it via the command prompt, I cannot find the right way to pass the command so it can correctly pass the switch.

Comment: I'm aware of how (switch)parameters work, thank you. I was asking about `$LogRun`, not `-LogRun`. Where does the variable you're passing to that parameter come from?